# Reversed Binary Numbers

Tags: algorithm, c, bitwise

Here is my code for "**Reverse Binary Numbers**" in C.

> **Problem**
>
> Your task will be to write a program for reversing numbers in binary.
>   For instance, the binary representation of 13 is 1101, and reversing
>   it gives 1011, which corresponds to number 11.
>
> **Input**
>
> The input contains a single line with an integer \$N\$, (where
>   \$1≤N≤1000000000\$ ).
>
> **Output** Output one line with one integer, the number we get by reversing the binary representation of \$N\$.
>
> **Sample 1**
>
> - input `13`
> - output `11`
>
> **Sample 2**
>
> - input `47`
> - output `61`

It's pretty efficient, but not the best. I wanted to improve the runtime. So I am looking for suggestions to improve the code.

**Code**

```
//Reverse Binary

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DIVISOR 2
#define MAX 50

int main() {
  int r, q, n, m = 1, num = 0, i = 0, len;
  int res[MAX];
  char str[MAX];

  scanf("%d", &n);

  do {

    q = n / DIVISOR;
    r = n % DIVISOR;

    res[i] = r; 

    n = q;

    i++;

  } while(n > 0);

  len = i;
  m = 1;

  for(; i > 0; i--) {
    if(res[i - 1] != 0) {
      num += res[i - 1] * m;
    }
    m *= DIVISOR;
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "%d", num);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Division and multiplication are relatively computationally costly operations compared to shifts and `AND` operations.  Try to reformulate your answer in terms of `>>` and `&` and you will likely find a performance gain.

Other things I noticed that may help you improve your program:

### Eliminate unused variables

Both `len` and `str` are unused and may be eliminated from the program.

### Try to put the loop exit condition at the top of the loop

Instead of using `do {...} while`, prefer to use `while {...}` or a `for` loop.  in your case this will also neatly solve the problem that occurs when the user types in a negative number.

### `return 0` is not needed at the end of main

Any modern compiler will automatically assume that getting to the end of `main` means that the program has executed successfully and will generate the equivalent of `return 0` at the end.  It is not necessary to write it.

### Check the return value of `scanf`

The call to `scanf` can fail, in which case it will return 0.  Your code should check for that.

### If your input says you will only have positive numbers, use `unsigned`

Instead of `"%d"` it would make more sense to say `scanf("%u", &n)` since the inputs cannot be negative.  Note that this will not *prevent* negative numbers from being input, but it makes the expectation clear within the code.  Alternatively, check for negative number input to make the code more robust.

### Consider verifying that your data type will hold the maximum value

The input specification says that the input numbers are all in the range of \$1 \le N \le 1,000,000,000\$ but an `int` isn't necessarily large enough on all platforms.  Since it takes 30 bits to express that number, and because it's unsigned, it would probably make more sense to use a `uint_fast32_t` type defined in `<stdint.h>` which is a fast integer type containing at least 32 bits.

Comment: You can generally count on the compiler to do the obvious optimizations like using shifts instead of multiply/divide. No need to rewrite arithmetic as bit shifts just to eke out a little extra performance if it is going to make your code any harder to read. In this case, however, since he really does want to do bit shifts, using the bit shift operators makes perfect sense and adds to the readability of the code. But if he were doing arithmetic and wanted to multiply a number by 2, he should use multiplication instead of trying to out optimize the compiler by using bit shifting.

Answer (score 4):

Using bit trick you can reverse the bits in a number without needing arrays to store temporary results.

modifying one solution [I found online](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious):

```
unsigned int input;
scanf("%u", &input);
unsigned int result = 0;

while(input !=0)
{   
  result  <<= 1;
  result  |= input & 1;
  input >>=1;
}
fprintf(stdout, "%d", result );
```

Comment: You might want to consider what happens if `input < 0`.

Comment: @Edward except it's not allowed to be (see input contract)

Comment: this will fail when there are leading 0 bits in the input number.  suggest a for loop that iterates 32 times

Comment: @user3629249 check the contract, inputting 47 `0b10111` should return 61 `0b111101`

Comment: It should be the *code* that checks the contract.

Comment: @Edward I'm treating like it's the C spec, you give me something outside the spec you specified then *anything* can happen.

Comment: Expecting other *code* to comply with the contract is fine.  Expecting every *user* to do so is the recipe for fragile and exploitable software.

Comment: Better to use `"%u"` with `unsigned` than `scanf("%d", &input);`

Answer (score 4):

Putting all your code in the main method is seldom a good idea.

Additionally, `int` is only guaranteed to 16 bits, you need to use `long`.

This problem lends itself to creating a function to do the work for you:

```
unsigned long bitReverse(unsigned long value)
{
    unsigned long result = 0;
    while (value)
    {
        /* make space by shifting left on the result */
        result <<= 1;
        /* add the low bit in to the space */
        result |= value & 1;
        /* get a new low bit. */
        value >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The above function takes the low-bit off of the input value, and feeds them to the high bits of the output value.

I have put this together in [a simple ideone](http://ideone.com/J4jK61)

Comment: this fails when there are leading 0 bits in the input value

Comment: @user3629249 - works fine for me: http://ideone.com/J4jK61

Comment: I'd suggest two changes: 1) make all of the numbers `unsigned` rather than `int` and 2) use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop as: `for (result=0;value;value>>=1)`

Comment: What happens when you input `6`?

Comment: @Edward: From ideone: `In 6 out 3`

Comment: It's not clear to me that `3` is the correct response to input `6`.

Comment: The answer to that, @Edward, heavily depends on what you expect as output to `1`, similarly 2. I guess there are uncertainties in the question... it's not well specified.

Answer (score 2):

### Minor bugs

The problem states that *N* may be as large as 10<sup>9</sup>.  An `int` is only guaranteed to hold values [up to 32767](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types).  Granted, systems with a 16-bit `int` are extremely rare these days, but you should use a `long` for correctness.  Since we are working with digits, `unsigned long` would be more appropriate.

It is conventional to output a newline at the end of your output.

### Trimming the fat

You have a lot of variables, which makes it hard to follow what is going on.

You should always compile with warnings enabled.  Your compiler would have told you…

> ```
> 13:8: warning: unused variable 'str' [-Wunused-variable]
>   char str[MAX];
>        ^
> 1 warning generated.
> ```

You have other unnecessary (`len`, `q`, `r`) and cryptically named (`m`, `res`) variables, as well as superfluous includes (`<stdlib.h>` and `<string.h>`).  `DIVISOR` is also being used as a multiplier, so I would rename it to `BASE`.  The length of the array (50) seems completely arbitrary; there is a systematic way to figure out exactly how much storage you need.

```c
//Reverse Binary

#include <stdio.h>

#define BASE 2
#define NUM_DIGITS (8 * sizeof(unsigned long))

int main() {
  unsigned long n;
  int i = 0;
  int digits[NUM_DIGITS];       // Least-significant digit first

  scanf("%lu", &n);

  do {
    digits[i++] = n % BASE;
  } while ((n = n / BASE) != 0);

  unsigned long num = 0, multiplier = 1;

  for (i--; i >= 0; i--) {
    num += digits[i] * multiplier;
    multiplier *= BASE;
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "%lu\n", num);
}
```

### Rewriting

The key to the solution lies in picking an invariant: on each iteration of the loop, transfer one digit from the input to the output.

I would write it using a `for` loop, so that you can see at a glance what happens to the input just by looking at the loop header.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define BASE 2

int main() {
    unsigned long in, out = 0;
    for (scanf("%lu", &in); in; in /= BASE) {
        out = (out * BASE) + (in % BASE);
    }
    printf("%lu\n", out);
}
```

Since the problem deals with binary digits, it seems natural to write the same algorithm using bitwise operations.  (When compiling with optimizations enabled, the generated executable is likely to be identical.)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long in, out = 0;
    for (scanf("%lu", &in); in; in >>= 1) {
        out = (out << 1) | (in & 1);
    }
    printf("%lu\n", out);
}
```

Comment: "systems with a 16-bit int are extremely rare these days".  Do not agree about the rarity.   Microchip made over a billion processors last year.   A significant percentage of those have a native 8 or 16-bit integer size.  Many C compilers use 16-bit `int` for them.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that ALL the bits need to be reversed, not just the '1' bits. The following code compiles, links cleanly and works properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INT_BITS (32)

int main()
{
    unsigned int input;
    unsigned int result = 0;
    unsigned int i; // loop counter

    printf("\nEnter the unsigned Number: ");
    if( 1 != scanf("%u", &input) )
    { // scanf failed
        perror( "scanf failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    for(i=0;i<INT_BITS;i++)
    {
      result  <<= 1;
      result  |= input & 1;
      input >>=1;
    } // end for

    fprintf(stdout, "%u\n", result );

    return(0);
} // end function: main
```

Comment: I believe you have mis-read the spec. Not all bits need to be reversed, just the bits from the most significant *set* bit.... The spec says input 13 needs to become 11 .... and so on.

Comment: Additionally, your definition of 32-bits to an int reminded me that int is only guaranteed as 16 bits in C. It's not necessarily 32-bit at all.

Comment: OP's sample #1 has input `13` and output `11`.  This code gives output `2952790016`.